# Neo4j 3.0.6 Uniqueness constraint being violated with MERGE

Tags: merge, neo4j, cypher, unique, acid

I am running Neo4j 3.0.6, and am importing large amounts of data into a fresh instance from multiple sources. I enforce uniqueness using the following constraint:

```sql
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Person) ASSERT n.id IS UNIQUE
```

I will then import data and relationships from multiple sources and multiple threads:

```sql
MERGE (mother:Person{id: 22})
MERGE (father:Person{id: 55})
MERGE (self:Person{id: 128})
SET self += {name: "Alan"}
MERGE (self)-[:MOTHER]->(mother)
MERGE (self)-[:FATHER]->(father)
```

Meanwhile, on another thread, but still on the same Neo4j server and bolt endpoint, I'll be importing the rest of the data:

```sql
MERGE (husband:Person{id: 55})
MERGE (self:Person{id: 22})
SET self += {name: "Phyllis"}
MERGE (self)-[:HUSBAND]->(husband)
```

```sql
MERGE (wife:Person{id: 22})
MERGE (self:Person{id: 55})
SET self += {name: "Angel"}
MERGE (self)-[:WIFE]->(wife)
```

```sql
MERGE (brother:Person{id: 128})
MERGE (self:Person{id: 92})
SET self += {name: "Brian"}
MERGE (self)-[:BROTHER]->(brother)
MERGE (self)<-[:BROTHER]-(brother)
```

Finally, if I run the constraint command again, I get this:

```
Unable to create CONSTRAINT ON ( Person:Person ) ASSERT Person.id IS UNIQUE:
Multiple nodes with label `Person` have property `id` = 55:
  node(708823)
  node(708827)
```

There is no guarantee which order the records will be processed in. What ends up happening is multiple records for the same `(:Person{id})` get created, but only one gets populated with `name` data.

It appears there is a race condition in Neo4j that if two `MERGE`'s happen for the same id at the same time, they both will be created.  Is there a way to avoid this race condition? Is there a way to establish the necessary locks?

<sub>Possible duplicate: [Neo4J 2.1.3 Uniqueness Constraint Being Violated, Is This A Bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878581/neo4j-2-1-3-uniqueness-constraint-being-violated-is-this-a-bug) But this is for `CREATE` and [this google groups answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/g7TDt0xY5BE) indicates that `CREATE` behaves differently than `MERGE` in respect to constraints.</sub>

Comment: Deleted my answer, as it no longer applies to your updated description. I'll submit another answer if I can think up some better solution.

Comment: Thank you InverseFalcon. Im sorry my mistaken syntax prompted you to write such a complete and useful answer that only I got to see. I gave you some extra rep to hopefully make up for it :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens if you change your SET into both `ON CREATE SET...` and `ON MERGE SET...` Do you still end up with duplicate nodes?

Comment: Would you mind providing an example of what that would look like given any of my examples?

Comment: Ah I see.. updating my code to try that

Comment: Mind you I'm not too confident in this as a solution, just wanted to confirm that this also results in duplicate nodes.

Comment: It does result in duplicates.

Comment: Could the duplicates have been created *before* you created the uniqueness constraint?

Comment: @cybersam No, because if you try to create the constraint, you get the error "Unable to create CONSTRAINT..."

Comment: OK. Could the duplicates have been created by a prior version of your Cypher code? For example, if you used `CREATE` earlier instead of `MERGE`?

Comment: You need to create the create the constraint and ensure it is online before you begin to run `MERGE` statements. You can verify the constraint is online by running `:schema` in the browser or `CALL db.constraints`. If the constraint has not been created and is online, there is no guarantee of uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you can get an implicit lock on some node and then use that for synchronization, but I think that effectively serializes the processing, so the processing won't really be processed concurrently.

Overall I think a better approach would be to abandon processing the same kind of data in multiple threads and just do a single import on one thread to MERGE :Persons and set their properties.

After that's imported, then you can process the creation of your relationships, with the understanding that you'll be MATCHing instead of MERGEing on :Persons.